# Celery tasks don't send email to admins on logger critical messages

Tags: python, django, celery

My celery tasks don't send an email to application admins each time I call logger.critical.

I'm building a Django application. The current configuration of my project, allows the admins of the application to receive an email each time a logger.critical message is created. This was pretty straight forward to set up, I just followed the documentation on both projects (celery and Django). For some reason, which I'm not figuring out, the code that runs inside a celery task, does not have the same behavior, It doesn't send an email to the application admin each time the logger.critical message is created.

Does celery actually even allow this to be done? 
Am I missing some configuration? 
Does anyone got this problem and was able to solve it?

Using:

- Django 1.11
- Celery 4.3

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have a checklist I check every time. Does the way I import the celery app also import my whole correct Django settings? You can check your logging settings by printing them inside your tasks to check it out. Is the celery task code path in one of my installed apps? Are the `__init__.py` files correct? Am I correctly addressing the task in scheduler or have I imported the task correctly where I am using it?

Comment: What is your code? It's harder to get help without showing the code that doesn't work as expected :)

At minimal, someone would try first to reproduce the issue that you have, then suggest a working solution.

Comment: @babis21 you can reproduce by making a logger critical inside a celery task,  on any project with Django logger configured to send admin emails. Thanks

Comment: for this feature better use sentry except implement it. sentry easy to use and send very good info about error occurred in django web application.

Comment: how you are calling the task can we see

Comment: @Erfan isn't sentry a paid tool?

Comment: could you share code?

Answer (score 8):

As stated in the documentation Celery overrides the current logging configuration to apply its own, it also says that you can set `CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER` to `False` in your Django settings to prevent this behavior, what is not well documented is that this is not really working at the moment.

In my opinion you have 2 options:

### 1.  Prevent Celery to override your configuration (really) using the `setup_logging` signal

Open your `celery.py` file and add the following:

```py
from celery.signals import setup_logging

@setup_logging.connect
def config_loggers(*args, **kwags):
    pass
```

After that your file should look more or less like this:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.signals import setup_logging

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

app = Celery('myproject')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@setup_logging.connect
def config_loggers(*args, **kwags):
    pass
```

**However** I would avoid this option unless you have a really good reason because in this way you will lose the default task logging handled by Celery, which is quite good to have.

### 2.  Use a specific logger

You can define a custom logger in your Django `LOGGING` configuration and use it in your task, eg:

**Django settings:**

```py
LOGGING = {
    # ... other configs ...
    'handlers': {
        'my_email_handler': {
            # ... handler configuration ...
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        # ... other loggers ...
        'my_custom_logger': {
            'handlers': ['my_email_handler'],
            'level': 'CRITICAL',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

**Tasks:**

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('my_custom_logger')

@shared_task
def log():
    logger.critical('Something bad happened!')
```

I believe this is the best approach for you because, as far as I understand, you need to manually log messages, and this allows you to keep using the Celery logging system.

Answer (score -3):

From Celery docs:

> By default any previously configured handlers on the root logger will be removed. If you want to customize your own logging handlers, then you can disable this behavior by setting worker_hijack_root_logger = False.

Celery installs own logger that you can obtain using `get_task_logger()` call. I assume you wrote your own logger that does the logic you described in the original question. Read more about [Celery logging](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#logging) to find out how to disable this behaviour and tweak Celery to your needs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm using the default Django logger, either in the web app or in celery tasks.